# javascript - get two numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string like:

```
text-345-3535
```

The numbers can change.
How can I get the two numbers from it and store that into two variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = "text-345-3535"

var arr = str.split(/-/g).slice(1);
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/BZgUt/

This will give you an array with the last two number sets.

If you want them in separate variables add this.

```
var first = arr[0];
var second = arr[1];
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/BZgUt/1/

---

**EDIT:**

Just for fun, here's another way.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/BZgUt/2/

```
var str = "text-345-3535",first,second;

str.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)$/,function(str,p1,p2) {first = p1;second = p2});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var m = "text-345-3535".match(/.*?-(\d+)-(\d+)/);
```

m[1] will hold "345" and m[2] will have "3535"

Answer (score 2):

If you're not accustomed to regular expressions, @patrick dw's answer is probably better for you, but this should work as well:

```
var strSource = "text-123-4567";
var rxNumbers = /\b(\d{3})-(\d{4})\b/
var arrMatches = rxNumbers.exec(strSource);
var strFirstCluster, strSecondCluster;
if (arrMatches) {
    strFirstCluster = arrMatches[1];
    strSecondCluster = arrMatches[2];
}
```

This will extract the numbers if it is exactly three digits followed by a dash followed by four digits. The expression can be modified in many ways to retrieve exactly the string you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
    var text = "text-123-4567";

```
if(text.match(/-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/)) {
        var x = Text.match(/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/);
                alert(x[0]);
                alert(x[1]);
                alert(x[2]);    
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this (using String tokenizer).

```
int idx=0; int tokenCount;
String words[]=new String [500];
String message="text-345-3535";
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(message,"-");
tokenCount=st.countTokens();
System.out.println("Number of tokens = " + tokenCount);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) // is there stuff to get?
    {words[idx]=st.nextToken(); idx++;}
for (idx=0;idx<tokenCount; idx++)
    {System.out.println(words[idx]);}
}
```

### output

words[0] =>text
words[1] => 345
words[2] => 3535